# how do I make ASPX Web pages without file extensions?

Tags: asp.net, url

I have notice that stackoverflow.com does not have file extensions on their pages. How would I do this with an aspx web site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URLs aren't actually pointing to files. They're using URL rewrite rules to convert the URL to a database query and feed the output back to a specified page (whose URL isn't displayed).

**Edit:** For clarification
SO uses MVC, so the url is pointing to a specific controller action (with or without parameters, depending on the page). The action runs some code to grab data or whatever and passes it to a corresponding view, which is basically an html template that fills in the info provided by the action and renders the page.

Comment: Umm.  Sort of.  It actually invokes a controller action method, which probably does a db query and renders a particular view related to the url.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? It's completely gibberish. :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a great article from Scott Guthrie:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

It covers off all scenarios: IIS 6, IIS7, using third party URL rewriting tools, etc.

Answer (score 6):

[MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

They use MVC

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow uses ASP.NET MVC which does clean URLs out of the box.

Basically what you need is something that takes the clean URL and then maps it to a standard .NET URL with your passing in extra 'directories' as parameters. e.g. rewriting /blog/post-no-one to /blog.aspx?id=post-no-one.

The new IIS has a rewrite plug in that will do this for you if you want to do it with traditional ASP.NET:

[Using URL rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/)

Or you can roll your own by overriding HttpModule and doing rewrites in there. Here is a complex example of that:

[URL rewriting engine](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030522.htm)

Answer (score 2):

As a few people have mentioned, SO is using the URL routing engine included with MVC. They've actually made the code available via CodePlex, so you can use it inside of a webforms-based ASP.NET site.

Phil Haack has a nice summary of how to do this:

[Routing w/WebForms](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx)

It includes samples, links, etc. that should be helpful in getting you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use ASP.Net without going the MVC route (MVC is awesome, btw) you can route requests using a HTTP Handler.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)